# Can a blimp skip on the atmosphere?

Tags: gravity, velocity, atmospheric-science, molecular-dynamics

What would happen if a large blimp slowing from an orbital speed skims the atmosphere gradually?

Would a proper angle allow it to skip like a rock to water over until it slows with each dip?

Would it at gradually just slow down if you angle it to maintain altitude from the top of the atmosphere while descending from orbit?

Comment: Since you've asked a couple of questions about airships and space travel, you might be interested in this: http://www.jpaerospace.com/atohandout.pdf Researchers have definitely thought about and are still thinking about roles for airships in reaching low Earth orbit. I'm no aerospace engineer, but the presentation I attach does seem to make sense to someone with a general physics knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!  Theoretically: yes.  There should be some velocity at which a blimp could skip off of the atmosphere... but there are some peculiarities in the problem.

- 1) Blimp's get lift from their average density being similar or less than that of the ambient air.  Once they are very high altitudes, the surrounding air is extremely low density, so it would be almost impossible to have a blimp float there.
- 2) To really have a "skip" (like a bounce) there would need to be a fairly abrupt change in the air density (like the transition from air to water in the case of a skipping stone).  It might not be practical to reach high enough velocities for that to be the case for a blimp in the upper atmosphere.

---

[There is a really nice paper (undergraduate level) that describes the physics of rock skipping by Lyderic Bocquet (DOI: 10.1119/1.1519232)](http://www.phys.ens.fr/~lbocquet/AJPricochets.pdf).  The overall idea is that there is a lift force produced by the water, and that lift force needs to be greater than that of gravity to push the rock (or blimp!) back up into the air.

Comment: Te blimp would be on a degrading orbit outside the atmosphere.